# How to trap intellij plugin uninstall event

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

During **uninstall** obviously there is a need for some plugins to free up resources that may have been created during or outside the plugin installation event.

Is there *really* no callback provision within the *intellij* plugin framework for this?

I note that this [same question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000141270--Intellij-Idea-Plugin-Is-there-any-way-to-catch-the-Plugin-Uninstall-event-) was asked in a different forum with no response but hope that SO can do better.

Comment: The linked question was submitted in the wrong forum, so it was missed by IntelliJ IDEA team. I've moved it to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development and asked the responsible person to have a look and reply. If you have any plug-in development questions for IntelliJ IDEA platform, the dev forum is the proper place to ask.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank-you! Have found a [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000156564-Hook-for-plugin-uninstall-process) at that site that addresses this very issue.